# Stuck at making double quote work inside heredoc

Tags: bash

I'm trying to run this code:

```
    while read Item; do
        export environmentVariables="$environmentVariables\n      - $Item"
    done <<< "$(
        cat /LocalSecrets/EnvironmentVariables.json |
        jq -r 'to_entries[] | "\(.key)=\(.value)"' |
    )"
```

I have a simple JSON file at `/LocalSecrets/EnvironmentVariables.json`. It's a simple key/value pair JSON object:

```
{
    "FirstKey": "FirstValue",
    "SecondKey": "SecondValue",
    "ThirdKey": "ThirdValue"
}
```

And I want to read it using `jq` and append them all to a shell variable `$environmentVariables` like:

```
FirstKey=FirstValue
SecondKey=SecondValue
ThirdKey=ThirdValue
```

But since `jq` needs double quotes in its command, and I need to use heredoc to preserve the `$environmentVariables` in the current shell in the loop, I'm stuck. That code does not run and it has syntactic errors.

What should I do? I'm open to other solutions too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you have properly placed double quotes inside your heredoc. But the last `|` is not needed, it yields syntax error.

The first parameter assignment gives you an extra new line, but the following should work. Using heredoc:

```
while read item; do
    export environmentVariables="$environmentVariables\n$item"
done <<< "$(
    cat /LocalSecrets/EnvironmentVariables.json |
    jq -r 'to_entries[] | [.key, .value] | join("=")'
)"
```

Same, but using process substitution:

```
while read item; do
    export environmentVariables="$environmentVariables\n$item"
done < <(cat /LocalSecrets/EnvironmentVariables.json |
jq -r 'to_entries[] | [.key, .value] | join("=")')
```

`<(commands)` is [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution), the result of commands' execution appears as a special file name and is passed to `while` with a simple input redirection `<`.

Alternatively, you can use simple pipe but instruct shell to execute its last element (`while`) in the current shell environment, allowing to preserve your variable value:

```
shopt -s lastpipe
cat /LocalSecrets/EnvironmentVariables.json |
jq -r 'to_entries[] | [.key, .value] | join("=")' |
while read item
do
    export environmentVariables="$environmentVariables\n$item"
done
```

Also, if you actually need newline characters in your variable, and not literally `\n` characters, you simply do:

```
export environmentVariables=$(
    cat /LocalSecrets/EnvironmentVariables.json |
    jq -r 'to_entries[] | [.key, .value] | join("=")'
)
```

Comment: what is that weird `< <` sign? Can you explain a little bit too? Thank you so much. It worked.